# How can I assign a key to an item in my array in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand how to assign a key to my array elements. I need to assign a key to each card traveled with my map function. I was trying many things and nothing. I look forward to your prompt help. Thank you.

```
return( 
<Fragment>
<ul>
<Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
    { products && products.map((item, index) => {
        return(
        // Comienza la tarjeta.
            <Card className={classes.card}>
              <CardHeader
                avatar={
                  <Avatar aria-label="recipe" src={item.image} className={classes.avatar}/>
                }
                action={
                    obtainRoleUser() === true?
                    <div>
                        <Settings
                            aria-controls="customized-menu"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={handleClick}
                        />
                        <StyledMenu
                            id="customized-menu"
                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                            keepMounted
                            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                            onClose={handleClose}
                        >
                            <StyledMenuItem>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <Edit fontSize="small" />
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary="Editar Producto" />
                            </StyledMenuItem>
                            <StyledMenuItem>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <Delete fontSize="small" />
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary="Borrar Producto" />
                            </StyledMenuItem>
                        </StyledMenu>
                    </div>
                    : 
                    <div/>
                }
                title={item.name + " " + index}
                subheader={"Categoria: " + item.category}
              />
              <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={item.image}
                title={item.image.title}
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                  {item.description}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <h5>{item.price + "Bs"}</h5>
              <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
                  <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="add to favorites">
                     <Favorite />
                  </IconButton>
                  <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="add to shopping cart">
                     <AddShoppingCart />
                  </IconButton>
              </Grid>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
        );
    })
    }
  </Grid>
   </ul>
  </Fragment>
  );
  }
```

I need assign a key or number for each target or products in my array. I can't resolve this, i have many issues with key and index products array.

Comment: You have already assigned a key to your top level element inside map `<div key={index}>`. If you have something more unique in your array then use that else index is okay.

Comment: I do not use what I put, because I do not assign a number to the entire card when I do an onClick event and I want to know which card I clicked.

Comment: You want to get the index of a particular card on onClick?

Comment: Yessss, I not idea how do it @AtinSingh

Comment: If you need to create onClick events or other node specific listeners you will need to use refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html (or with hooks API: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 1):

```
    return( 
    <Fragment>
    <ul>
    <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
        { products && products.map((item, index) => {
            return(
            // Comienza la tarjeta.
                <Card className={classes.card} key={item.id}>
                  <CardHeader
                    avatar={
                      <Avatar aria-label="recipe" src={item.image} className={classes.avatar}/>
                    }
                    action={
                        obtainRoleUser() === true?
                        <div>
                            <Settings
                                aria-controls="customized-menu"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}
                            />
                            <StyledMenu
                                id="customized-menu"
                                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                keepMounted
                                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                                onClose={handleClose}
                            >
                                <StyledMenuItem>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        <Edit fontSize="small" />
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary="Editar Producto" />
                                </StyledMenuItem>
                                <StyledMenuItem>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        <Delete fontSize="small" />
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary="Borrar Producto" />
                                </StyledMenuItem>
                            </StyledMenu>
                        </div>
                        : 
                        <div/>
                    }
                    title={item.name + " " + index}
                    subheader={"Categoria: " + item.category}
                  />
                  <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={item.image}
                    title={item.image.title}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                      {item.description}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions disableSpacing>
                <h5>{item.price + "Bs"}</h5>
                  <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
                      <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="add to favorites">
                         <Favorite />
                      </IconButton>
                      <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="add to shopping cart">
                         <AddShoppingCart />
                      </IconButton>
                  </Grid>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
            );
        })
        }
      </Grid>
       </ul>
      </Fragment>
      );
      }
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use array index. Instead, use the intrinsict id of item (item.id, for example, if it exists)

Comment: I mean to key prop, but that is ok too. Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys below the third sample code

Comment: so you can item.id which would be unique to each of the array element

Answer (score -1):

Pass an index value in as your second parameter and use it to set the component's id:

```js
    return (
        <div>
            {myArr.map((el, idx) => {
                <MyComponent
                    key={idx}
                    title={el.title}
                    content={el.content}
                />
            })}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: This will throw warnings about using the array index as a key

Comment: From the docs "We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state."

Comment: @JonB That's *if* the order may change. Otherwise its a perfectly acceptable practice.

Comment: Yes but putting it as an example doesn't explain that, people come to SO and just cut & paste code so that might introduce a bug in certain cases and the Dev wouldn't understand why.